# How to reproduce some attractive pseudo-code

Tags: beamer, itemize, mdframed

I am trying to reproduce:

[image]

I have made some progress with the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{framed} 
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\title{Beamer Template}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{itemize}[label={}]
    \item \textsc{Traverse}($s$)
     \vspace{0.5cm}
    \item put $\color{blue}s$ into the \textcolor{green}{bag} 
    \item while the \textcolor{green}{bag} is not empty
    \begin{itemize}
        \item take $\color{blue}u$ from the bag
        \item if $\color{blue}u$ unmarked
        \item \textcolor{red}{mark} $\color{blue}u$
        \item for every edge $\color{blue}(u,v)$
        \begin{itemize}
            \item put $\color{blue}v$ into the bag
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{itemize}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To complete this I need:

- Fit frame to text
- Make the frame thicker
- Find the right font
- Find the right colors

I can do the final one. How can I do the other three?

Comment: You also need to indent after the if statement.  Is it bold Courier?

Comment: Take a look at the packages for pseudocode (and/or listings). At least my personal favorite algorithm2e (seems to) have the required flexibility to create a format like you want with little pain. If there is extensive use, that is; if it is a few algorithms only doing the variable and so on coloring "by hand" is simpler.

Comment: The font is Computer Modern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try something entirely different.

## article (report, or book) document classes

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbset{
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colback=white,
}

\definecolor{code-yellow}{RGB}{232, 168, 24}
\definecolor{code-blue}{RGB}{0, 114, 178}
\definecolor{code-green}{RGB}{0, 158, 115}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[text width=5cm]
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,mathescape=true]{text}
|\textsc{Traverse}|(|\color{code-blue}{$s$}|)

put |\color{code-blue}{$s$}| into the |\textcolor{code-yellow}{bag}|
while the |\textcolor{code-yellow}{bag}| is not empty
  take |$\color{code-blue}u$| from the |\textcolor{code-yellow}{bag}|
  if |\color{code-blue}{$u$}| unmarked
    |\textcolor{code-green}{mark}| |$\color{code-blue}u$|
    for every edge |$\color{code-blue}(u,v)$|
        put |$\color{code-blue}v$| into the |\textcolor{code-yellow}{bag}|
\end{minted}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

## beamer document class

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbset{
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colback=white,
}

\definecolor{code-yellow}{RGB}{232, 168, 24}
\definecolor{code-blue}{RGB}{0, 114, 178}
\definecolor{code-green}{RGB}{0, 158, 115}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tcolorbox}[text width=5.5cm]
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,mathescape=true]{text}
|\textsc{Traverse}|(|\color{code-blue}{$s$}|)

put |\color{code-blue}{$s$}| into the |\textcolor{code-yellow}{bag}|
while the |\textcolor{code-yellow}{bag}| is not empty
  take |$\color{code-blue}u$| from the |\textcolor{code-yellow}{bag}|
  if |\color{code-blue}{$u$}| unmarked
    |\textcolor{code-green}{mark}| |$\color{code-blue}u$|
    for every edge |$\color{code-blue}(u,v)$|
        put |$\color{code-blue}v$| into the |\textcolor{code-yellow}{bag}|
\end{minted}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: code with minted]

Comment: Can  |\textcolor{code-green}{mark}|  be abbreviated to |\green{mark}| by defining new commands?

Comment: @Anush, sure! Just define what you need: `\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{code-green}{#1}}`

Comment: Picture perfect. It's a shame about requiring shell escape though.

Comment: @fomin, don't you have access to your shell? invoking `pdflatex -shell-escape <tex file>` doesn't seem so bad anymore. Even most editors have options to set the flag. If you need help there, just let me know…

Comment: You are right. I have set a menu option in TeXStudio now.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `semiverbatim`, that's built in `beamer`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\title{Beamer Template}

\newcommand{\Proc}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\ensuremath{\textcolor{varcolor}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Tag}[1]{\textcolor{tagcolor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Com}[1]{\textcolor{comcolor}{#1}}

\definecolor{varcolor}{RGB}{15,122,183}
\definecolor{tagcolor}{RGB}{230,159,3}
\definecolor{comcolor}{RGB}{10,161,119}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{semiverbatim}
\Proc{Traverse}(\Var{s})

put \Var{s} into the \Tag{bag} 
while the \Tag{bag} is not empty
  take \Var{u} from the bag
  if \Var{u} unmarked
    \Com{mark} \Var{u}
    for every edge \Var{(u,v)}
      put \Var{v} into the \Tag{bag}    
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{mdframed}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Don't forget the `fragile` option.

[image]

An alternative is to use `BVerbatim` from `fancyvrb`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\title{Beamer Template}

\newcommand{\Proc}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\ensuremath{\textcolor{varcolor}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Tag}[1]{\textcolor{tagcolor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Com}[1]{\textcolor{comcolor}{#1}}

\definecolor{varcolor}{RGB}{15,122,183}
\definecolor{tagcolor}{RGB}{230,159,3}
\definecolor{comcolor}{RGB}{10,161,119}

\newenvironment{pseudocode}
 {%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{lrbox}{\pseudocodebox}
  \fvset{commandchars=\\\{\}}
  \begin{BVerbatim}
 }
 {\end{BVerbatim}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\pseudocodebox}}}
\newsavebox{\pseudocodebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{pseudocode}
\Proc{Traverse}(\Var{s})

put \Var{s} into the \Tag{bag} 
while the \Tag{bag} is not empty
  take \Var{u} from the bag
  if \Var{u} unmarked
    \Com{mark} \Var{u}
    for every edge \Var{(u,v)}
      put \Var{v} into the \Tag{bag}    
\end{pseudocode}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As far as I know, `mdframed` always uses the whole text width. Check with `tcolorbox` for more powerful methods.

Comment: This is really nice, I had no idea about semiverbatim. Is there a way to make the box fit the text more tightly?

Comment: semiverbatim looks exactly what I need! I will combine the tcolorbox answer from phil-elkabat  with this answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Anush Not with `mdframed`, I believe. Anyway, there it is.

Comment: Thank you! I don't fully understand all of your code but I will try to study it.